# Excel Date to Text Conversion Error

Tags: excel, date, text, excel-formula

My Excel does not convert a simple date to a text. Instead, it will only convert the month. I tried different date formats und small/ capital letters to define the date format, but the result does not change.

I tried to sketch the problem in the following table:

```
             |    Date    | Date as Text
Cell Formula | 03.03.2009 | =TEXT(B7;"DD-MM-YYYY")
Cell Output  | 03.03.2009 | DD-03-YYYY
```

Comment: If you have a German Excel, then it must be `=TEXT(B7;"TT-MM-JJJJ")`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AxelRichter you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner (Daniel Methner) may do so too.. ( :

Answer (score 1):

The question owner used Excel in German language.

@AxelRichter suggested to use `=TEXT(B7;"TT-MM-JJJJ")` instead, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go On Format cells and search for standard type letter that your excel accept the Day and Years

[image]

Comment: This answer does not address the issue. Additionally the answer was already given in the comment section approximately 20 minutes before you answered here.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - seems like a valid contribution to me, if you go to "format cell" as JCode suggests then Daniel or anybody else should be able to see the default date format used, i.e. TT-MM-JJJJ, so that would give you the value you need for `TEXT` function

Comment: @barryhoudini The answer doesn't really add any value in my opinion. The question demonstrated that using `DD-MM-YYYY` wasn't working. This answer just provides an alternate way to reformat a cell, but doesn't address the fundamental issue that different characters must be used because it is a different language. I didn't upvote or downvote, just was giving the answerer info for future use as he is a new user.